# Gmod lua_openscript not working

Tags: lua

[image: This is what happens]

As you can see I believe everything is right where it should be however when I try to open the file with lua_openscript helloworld.lua it does absolutly nothing.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is your package.path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think print works in GMod, try this:

```
Msg("Hello World!\n");
```

Comment: Yeah it's weird, print should work but for some reason it doesn't work with GMOD.  Print is like standard lua code so I don't know why that was the problem.

Comment: GMod Lua removes and changes certain builtins (needlessly, imo). Though in my experience, print works fine...